# Pass javascript array to asp array

Tags: asp.net

I have a javascript array with values of checkbox selected.
I want to pass this javascript array to asp array so that I can update the database.

I am using Jquery to get checkbox value

```
$('.checkboxes_to_delete:checked').each(function (key, value)
{           
    dataToBeDeleted.push($(this).val());
    alert(dataToBeDeleted);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use your Javascript to put the values into a hidden textbox on your page, and then your ASP code can pull that value down like any other form value.

Answer (score 2):

Send your array using $.post:

```
//Javascript

var myarray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$.post("Default.aspx", { data: myarray }, function (r) { /* callback */ }, "text");
```

In the code-behind (Default.aspx.cs) you can access your array by using Request["data[]"].
Your data will be a CSV.

```
//C#

string v = Request["data[]"];
//v == "1,2,3,4,5"; (true)
```

Answer (score 2):

What I have done in the past is put the data from the JavaScript array into a hidden textbox with commas between the values. Then post-back and read the hidden textbox, and use string.Split() to seperate out into an array server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a [checkboxlist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) control?